# easy_localization switch language doesnt work

Tags: flutter

i have 2 Buttons where i can change the language. If i click the following code will executed.

this buttons are in my settings.dart file not in the main

```
onPressed: (context) async {                 await context.setLocale(const Locale('en', 'US')); 
 },
```

in the Debug console it says:

```
\[ Easy Localization\] \[INFO\] Locale en_US changed
\[ Easy Localization\] \[INFO\] Locale en_US saved
\[ Easy Localization\] \[DEBUG\] Build
\[ Easy Localization\] \[DEBUG\] Init Localization Delegate
\[ Easy Localization\] \[DEBUG\] Init provider

but

\[ Easy Localization\] \[DEBUG\] Load Localization Delegate
2
\[ Easy Localization\] \[DEBUG\] Load asset from assets/lang
```

is missing.

This is the configuration in my main:

```
void main() async {
WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

runApp(
EasyLocalization(
startLocale: const Locale('de', 'DE'),
supportedLocales: const \[Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('de', 'DE')\],
path: 'assets/lang', // Pfad zu den Übersetzungsdateien
fallbackLocale: const Locale(
'de', 'DE'),
```

Maybe someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive multiple language support; I've developed a demo on which you can check and have reference. It is available on github.

[Flutter Localization](https://github.com/Pranav2918/FlutterLocalization)

**Happy Fluttering!!**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the translation files are placed in the correct directory under the 'assets' folder:

```
assets/
  lang/
    en_US.json
    de_DE.json
```

Ensure that you have properly configured your pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/lang/
```

Next,
Check that you are initializing Easy Localization correctly in your main.dart file:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      startLocale: const Locale('de', 'DE'),
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('de', 'DE')],
      path: 'assets/lang', // Path to the translation files
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('de', 'DE'),
      // ...
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your fast answer:
in the pubspec.yaml its correct configured:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/lang/
```

the direction is also correct:

```
assets/lang/de-DE.json
assets/lang/en-EN.json
```

the startLocale is also loading correctly:

```
[ Easy Localization] [INFO] Start locale loaded de_DE
[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Build
[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init Localization Delegate
[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init provider
[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Load Localization Delegate
2
[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Load asset from assets/lang
```

Comment: You can simply upvote and/or accept the answer you like, there's no need to validate it further; this "answer" is not an answer that might help someone else with the same problem; ie, it's not an alternate answer, but a discussion, which pollutes rather than enhance the question. It's also possible to edit the question and make it more clear, if that would help other askers in the future.